# Exceptionally slow performance when retrieving secret with Azure Key Vault

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I am attempting to implement Azure Key Vault in my app so that it can retrieve stored secrets for use. I'm experiencing 12-15 seconds to retrieve a secret locally which is unacceptable in any capacity. Below is the code I am using to access my key vault and they specific secret name.

```
DefaultAzureCredential credential = new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions
{
      ExcludeAzureCliCredential = true,
      ExcludeAzureDeveloperCliCredential = true,
      ExcludeAzurePowerShellCredential = true,
      ExcludeEnvironmentCredential = true,
      ExcludeInteractiveBrowserCredential = true,
      ExcludeManagedIdentityCredential = false,
      ExcludeSharedTokenCacheCredential = true,
      ExcludeVisualStudioCodeCredential = true,
      ExcludeVisualStudioCredential = false,
      ExcludeWorkloadIdentityCredential = true
});
SecretClientOptions options = new SecretClientOptions()
{
      Retry =
      {
            Delay = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10),
            MaxDelay = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000),
            MaxRetries = 5,
            Mode = RetryMode.Exponential
      }
};

var client = new SecretClient(vaultUri: new Uri("my-vault-uri"), credential: credential, options: options);

KeyVaultSecret secret = isTestMode ? await client.GetSecretAsync("test-secret") : await client.GetSecretAsync("live-secret");
   
return secret.Value.ToString();
```

I currently am using Visual Studio credential for local development and (maybe) Managed Identity for deployed app (although I cannot figure out the proper access configuration so that will likely be another question posed.)

Has anyone else experienced this and solved for this? Waiting even 1 second for a secret to be retrieved is too slow.

Comment: Try with this code `var KV = new DefaultAzureCredential();  var KVURI = "https://KVName.vault.azure.net/";   var secrets = new SecretClient(new Uri(KVURI), KVCred);      var secret = secrets.GetSecret("YourSecretName");`

Comment: Locally this code lowered it to 9.5 seconds

Comment: Ok..deploy this code and check once

Comment: I am attempting to get your data to you. I know it fails but believe it does not have the proper permissions (still) to access. So trying to solve that before so I can get you the data you're requesting

Comment: Are you able to access the keys in portal ?

Comment: Does my code answer your question ?

Comment: I can access it in the portal. I am not sure if the code answers the question yet because I need to deploy the code to check if the performance issue is still there but the environment still doesn't have the rights needed to access the secret so I cannot determine yet

Comment: Are you able to access the keys locally?

Comment: Yes, I can access locally

Comment: Receiving this error in an environment, what additional do I need to configure? System.AggregateException: Retry failed after 4 tries. Retry settings can be adjusted in ClientOptions.Retry or by configuring a custom retry policy in ClientOptions.RetryPolicy. (An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions. (IP_ADDRESS))

Answer (score 0):

The `ManagedIdentityCredential` can take a long time to query. The best way to diagnose where the time is going is to trace and/or log. See https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/core/Azure.Core/samples/Diagnostics.md for details, but basically - and I also recommend just using a `ChainedTokenCredential` if you know exactly what you want:

```cs
using Azure.Core.Diagnostics;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;

if (args.Length < 2)
{
    throw new Exception($"Usage: {Environment.ProcessPath} {{vault-uri}} {{secret-name}}");
}

ChainedTokenCredential credential = new(
    new ManagedIdentityCredential(options: new()
    {
        Diagnostics =
        {
            IsLoggingEnabled = true,
        },
    }),
    new AzureCliCredential(options: new()
    {
        Diagnostics =
        {
            IsLoggingEnabled = true,
        },
    })
);

Uri vaultUri = new(args[0], UriKind.Absolute);
SecretClient client = new(vaultUri, credential, options: new()
{
    Diagnostics =
    {
        IsLoggingEnabled = true,
    },
});

using AzureEventSourceListener listener = AzureEventSourceListener.CreateConsoleLogger();

KeyVaultSecret secret = await client.GetSecretAsync(args[1]);
Console.WriteLine(secret.Value);
```

On my dev box, it wrote useful information to stdout including that `ManagedIdentityToken` took ~3 seconds (we vary the time intentionally) for each of 4 tries. You can change the `RetryOptions` of the `ManagedIdentityCredential` to shorten that or reduce retries, which `ChainedTokenCredential` allows you to do.

You can also just not add it if you know it's a dev environment, which it seems from your `isTestMode` check e.g.:

```cs
List<TokenCredential> credentials = new(capacity: 2);
if (isTestMode)
{
    credentials.Add(new ManagedIdentityCredential());
}
credentials.Add(new AzureCliCredential());
ChainedTokenCredential credential = new([.. credentials]);
```